# How to fix: java method in Anonymous class derived from <class> clashes with java method

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, anonymous-class

Android Studio is giving me a "[java method] in Anonymous class derived from [java class] clashes with [java method]" on both of the "throws CertificateException" parts of the following code.  The error adds: "overridden method does not throw javax.security.cert.CertificateException" How to satisfy the compiler?

Frankly, I am just as interested in understanding the general cause for this as the solution itself. Notice the two commented out lines.  I added them to see if it would prevent the error, hoping that the cause was simply that there was no code actually throwing the specified exception. Did not work.

I would so appreciate it if the correct answer could explain the precise reason for this (I don't why this is an "anonymous class").  This exact code is used in a lot of examples online and many of them seem to use it in a similar way (see [here](http://www.javased.com/?api=javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager)).

```
      X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() 
      {
          @Override
          public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
          {
           //if (authType == null)
           //     throw new javax.security.cert.CertificateException();
          }

          @Override
          public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
          {
          }

          @Override
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
          {
               return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
          }
        };
```

Comment: Why was my question downvoted??  It will help to give a reason if you want people to change their ways.  I don't mind improving my question, but you've said nothing about how.

Comment: Thought it was a reasonable question.  The error message doesn't obviously lead you to looking at imports and people coming into coding should feel comfortable asking questions. Up-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw `CertificateException` because the method defined in `X509TrustManager` does throw `java.security.cert.CertificateException`, which is not the same as the one you are trying to throw.

`javax.security.cert.CertificateException` is different from `java.security.cert.CertificateException`.

Comment: You're right.  Would you mind modifying your answer to specify that I can also just use "throws java.security.cert.CertificateException" instead of just "throws CertificateException" and that will also solve it.  I will then mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: You should fix your imports instead of using fully qualified names within the code. Remove the wrong import and press CTRL + Shift + O to optimize imports under Eclipse. :)

Comment: Ok.  I will do that.  I am using Android Studio btw.

Comment: Jerome - Do you have any idea why that guy downvoted my question?

Comment: It's a really basic question, solving import issues should be the very first knowledge a Java developer has.

Comment: Thx for response, but I don't see how knowing that there is both a javax.xxx and a java.xxx import is basic knowledge.  The throws didn't specify, thus obscuring the underlying issue.

Comment: The X509TrustManager clearly states in its imports the java.security.cert.CertificateException. It's a bad practice to specify types by  fully qualified names within the code. This is the role of imports. It's a common beginner mistake.